# Swagger-Net Display Request Duration

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle, swagger-net

I'm using [Swagger-Net](https://github.com/heldersepu/Swagger-Net) to be able to get Swagger documentation to my API without much hassle. It's going well, but I'm trying to configure it to display execution runtime of my API methods and I'm unable to do it.

I've seen a DisplayRequestDuration() inside a UseSwaggerUI, but in Swagger-Net I don't have that method. Also I tried the `c.AdditionalSettings.Add("displayRequestDuration ", true)` approach, but nothing.

Anyone knows how to add DisplayRequestDuration specifically to Swagger-Net?

Comment: No that is not a feature of Swagger-Net, where did you see that `DisplayRequestDuration()` ?? ... maybe that is a swagger-ui feature

Comment: I don't remember the exact page where I saw it, but yes I believe it's a swagger-ui feature. There's nothing similar in Swagger-Net? Thx for replying BTW.

Comment: I saw it and just created a PR for it: https://github.com/heldersepu/Swagger-Net/pull/114/files  ... just have to test that out and publish